# number of simultaneous connections on ftp

Tags: java, multithreading, ftp

Is it possible to know the number of simultaneous connections that a FTP server can supports with Java?

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering, I want to query an existing FTP server

Comment: AFAIK, current FTP protocol does not support get server configuration.

Answer (score 1):

You are asking about the feature of a FTP server whether it supports simultaneous connections.
Even if it supports, I do not think you can do much there using java except sending requests.